# Prolog grammar productions

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to learn how to write production rules in prolog. 
This is what I have.

```
paragraph --> sentence, paragraph ; [].
sentence --> proper_noun, [ ], verb, [ ], preposition, [ ], article, [ ], noun, period.
proper_noun --> [Jimmy] ; [Yancy] ; [Clementine] ; [Astrid].
verb --> [runs] ; [walks] ; [skips] ; [flies].
preposition --> [to] ; [at] ; [around] ; [through].
article --> [the]    ; [a].
noun --> [school] ; [house] ; [car] ; [spaceship].
period -->[.].
```

I tried to call it  using

```
 phrase( sentence, [Jimmy," ",walks," ",to," ",the," ",school], [] ), atom_codes( Output,[Jimmy," ",walks," ",to," ",the," ",school]).
```

It returned **false** as an output. Please help me understand where I went wrong and how I can write better grammars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `'Jimmy'` etc. (i.e. put all atoms starting with capital letters into quotes). Otherwise they are interpreted as logical variables. you do get lots of "Singleton variables" warnings.

you've also missed some parentheses, and made few more typos:

```
paragraph --> sentence, ( paragraph ; []).
sentence --> proper_noun, verb, preposition, article, noun, period.
proper_noun --> ['Jimmy'] ; ['Yancy'] ; ['Clementine'] ; ['Astrid'].
verb --> [runs] ; [walks] ; [skips] ; [flies].
preposition --> [to] ; [at] ; [around] ; [through].
article --> [the] ; [a].
noun --> [school] ; [house] ; [car] ; [spaceship].
period -->[.].
```

Testing it:

```
30 ?- phrase( sentence, ['Jimmy', walks, to, the, school, .], [] ).
true ;
false.
```

Comment: Hey. If you don't mind me asking how do the parenthesis help? And in the sentence production I want to include spaces as well. How would I do that? And can I use '|' instead of ';'

Comment: @BryanD'silva: yes, parenthesis allow nice shortcuts, inlining alternatives. Consider how elegant the right recursive paragraph//0 is. For spaces handling see library(dcg/basics). And you can use | instead of ;

Comment: @BryanD'silva w/out the (), it's read as `paragraph --> (sentence,  paragraph) ; [].`

Comment: @BryanD'silva ... so it never finishes; it always wants to get another paragraph. So, that fails; then it goes to the other possibility of empty input -- but the input wasn't empty. the correct parenthesizing means, get a sentence, and **then** *either* get another paragraph, *or* succeed when  the input is finished.